# Firebase Cloud Function To Sum up or aggregate values

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to sum up the price to bring up a total through the new firebase cloud functions

```
"Cart" : {
    "-Ksdasd50oR04q073k5" : {
      "ID" : 0.01,
      "price" : 20
    },
    "-KhOc0CGdsddihGB2N" : {
      "ID" : 001,,
      "price" : 20
    },
```

This is my start ,

```
exports.cartadd = functions.database.ref('Cart/{uid}').onWrite(event => {

   let ref = admin.database().ref('Cart/{uid}');
   return ref.once('value').then(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
        var total= 0;
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {

           total += snapshot.val().price;
        });
       console.log(total);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Under what conditions do you need to compute this sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
exports.cartadd = functions.database.ref('Cart').onWrite(event => {
      const snapshot = event.data;
      if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
        var total= 0;
        snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
           total += item.child('price').val();
        });
        console.log(total);
      }
  });
```

Comment: @Bob just curious to know if you have knowledge. We can get sum from mysql/sql from millions of records in milliseconds...but m afraid to fetch them and summing them on front end will not be good and can crash browser

Comment: @Luckyy: I don't know, but would guess that summing over that number of records would take longer.

Comment: wtf firebase, it has lot of limitations

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
exports.cartadd = functions.database.ref('Cart').onWrite(event => {
      const snapshot = event.data;
      const totalRef = admin.database().ref("Cart/total");
      if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
        let total= 0;
        snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
           total += item.child('price').val();
        });
        const transaction = totalRef.set(total).then(()=>{console.log(total);});
        return Promise.all([transaction]);
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the total needs to change, it should be a `var` not `const`.

Change

```
const total = 0;
```

to

```
var total = 0;
```

Comment: Yup Changed it But still no output is reflecting in my log

Answer (score 0):

```
total += child.val().price; // instead
```